# Sending data to a database in size-limited chunks

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, queue

I have a method which takes a parameter which is `Partition` enum. This method will be called by multiple background threads (15 max) around same time period by passing different value of `partition`. Here `dataHoldersByPartition` is a map of `Partition` and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder>`.

```
  private final ImmutableMap<Partition, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder>> dataHoldersByPartition;

  //... some code to populate entry in `dataHoldersByPartition`

  private void validateAndSend(final Partition partition) {  
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);
    Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = new HashMap<>();
    int totalSize = 0;      
    DataHolder dataHolder;
    while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll())  != null) {      
      byte[] clientKeyBytes = dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      if (clientKeyBytes.length > 255)
        continue;

      byte[] processBytes = dataHolder.getProcessBytes();
      int clientKeyLength = clientKeyBytes.length;
      int processBytesLength = processBytes.length;

      int additionalLength = clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;
      if (totalSize + additionalLength > 50000) {
        Message message = new Message(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder, partition);
        // here size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost
        sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.serialize());
        clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = new HashMap<>();
        totalSize = 0;
      }
      clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.put(clientKeyBytes, processBytes);
      totalSize += additionalLength;
    }
    // calling again with remaining values only if clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder is not empty
    if(!clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.isEmpty()) {
        Message message = new Message(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
        // here size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost
        sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.serialize());      
    }
  }
```

And below is my `Message` class:

```
public final class Message {
  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte recordsPartition;
  private final byte replicated;

  public Message(Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder, Partition recordPartition) {
    this.clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder;
    this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
    this.dataCenter = Utils.CURRENT_LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  // Output of this method should always be less than 50k always
  public byte[] serialize() {
    int bufferCapacity = getBufferCapacity(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder); // 36 + dataSize + 1 + 1 + keyLength + 8 + 2;

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferCapacity).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    // header layout
    byteBuffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.size())
        .putInt(bufferCapacity).putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin)
        .put(recordsPartition).put(replicated);

    // now the data layout
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.entrySet()) {
      byte keyType = 0;
      byte[] key = entry.getKey();
      byte[] value = entry.getValue();
      byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
      short valueLength = (short) value.length;

      ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
      long timestamp = valueLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();

      byteBuffer.put(keyType).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(valueLength)
          .put(value);
    }
    return byteBuffer.array();
  }

  private int getBufferCapacity(Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder) {
    int size = 36;
    for (Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.entrySet()) {
      size += 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
      size += entry.getKey().length;
      size += entry.getValue().length;
    }
    return size;
  }

    // getters and to string method here
}
```

Basically, what I have to make sure is whenever the `sendToDatabase` method is called, size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost. My `sendToDatabase` method sends byte array coming out from `serialize` method. And because of that condition I am doing below validation plus few other stuff. In the method, I will iterate `dataHolders` CLQ and I will extract `clientKeyBytes` and `processBytes` from it. Here is the validation I am doing:

- If the `clientKeyBytes` length is greater than 255 then I will skip it and continue iterating.
- I will keep incrementing the `totalSize` variable which will be the sum of `clientKeyLength` and `processBytesLength`, and this `totalSize` length should always be less than 50000 bytes.
- As soon as it reaches the 50000 limit, I will send the `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder` map to the `sendToDatabase` method and clear out the map, reset `totalSize` to 0 and start populating again.
- If it doesn't reaches that limit and `dataHolders` got empty, then it will send whatever it has.

I believe there is some bug in my current code because of which maybe some records are not being sent properly or dropped somewhere because of my condition and I am not able to figure this out. Looks like to properly achieve this 50k condition I may have to use `getBufferCapacity` method to correctly figure out the size before calling `sendToDatabase` method?

Comment: hmmm ok so what do you think now? Basically, what I have to make sure is whenever the `sendToDatabase` method is called, size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost. And for that I think I need to accurately count everything properly in `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder` map passed to `Message` class.

Comment: Two things that might cause problems come to mind: 1) Will there only ever be a single `DataHolder` per `Partition` having the same client key? If not, only the last stored bytes will be in the map. 2) Could there be a single `DataHolder` with process bytes > 50k? It would be nice to have an idea of what kind of data is in `dataHoldersByPartition`.

Comment: Did you solve this already?

Comment: @MickMnemonic not yet. I am still stuck on this. So on your point 2 it could be possible (may be it's a bot) that we can have single `DataHolder`  with `process bytes > 50k`, in this case, I will drop that record as it is and move to next one so maybe i will add a check on the length of `process bytes` and discard if it is more than 50k. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, its look good as per your logic. As you said it will always store the information which is less than 50K but it will actually store information till 50K. To make it less than 50K you have to change the if condition to `if (totalSize + additionalLength >= 50000)`.

If your codes still not fulfilling your requirement i.e. storing information  when   `totalSize + additionalLength`  is greater than 50k I can advise you few thinks.

As more than 50 threads call this method you need to consider two section in your codes to be synchronize.
One is global variable which is a container `dataHoldersByPartition` object. If multiple concurrent and parallel searches happened in this container object, outcome might not be perfect. Just check whether container type is synchronized or not. If not make this block like below:-

```
synchronized(this){
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders =  dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);
}
```

Now, I can give only two suggestion to fix this issue. One is instead of  `if (totalSize + additionalLength > 50000)`   this you can check the size of the object `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder`  `if(sizeof(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder) >= 50000)` (check appropriate method for sizeof in java). And second one is narrow down the area to check whether it is a side effect of multithreading or not. All these suggestion are to find out the area where exactly problem is and fix should be from your end only.

First check whether you method `validateAndSend`  is exactly satisfying your requirement or not. For that synchronize whole `validateAndSend` method first and check whether everything fine or still have the same result. If still have the same result that means it is not because of multithreading but your coding is not as per requirement. If its work fine that means it is a problem of multithreading. If method synchronization is fixing your issue but degrade the performance you just remove the synchronization from it and concentrate every small block of your code which might cause the issue and make it synchronize block and remove if still not fixing your issue. Like that finally you locate the block of code which is actually creating the issue and leave it as synchronize to fix it finally.

For example first attempt:-

```
  `private synchronize void validateAndSend`
```

Second attempts: Remove synchronize key words from the method and do the below step:-

```
           synchronize(this){
            Message message = new Message(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder, partition);                  
            sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.serialize());
     }
```

If you think that I did not correctly understand you please let me know.

Comment: Please read the code fully. Don't just look at the condition. That condition will make sure to send data if it is less than 50k because we are adding additionalLength to totalSize at the bottom.

Comment: Can you tell me what are all problem you are facing at the moment. Is this object `dataHoldersByPartition` chynchronize?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it out again from starting. `dataHoldersByPartition` is ImmutableMap so I believe it is already synchronize.

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

In your `validateAndSend` I would put whole data to the queue, and do whole processing in separate thread. Please consider command model. That way all threads are going to put their load on queue. Consumer thread has all the data, all the information in place, and can process it quite effectively. The only complicated part is sending response / result back to calling thread. Since in your case that is not a problem - the better. There are some more benefits of this pattern - please look at [netflix/hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix).